# Is a method thread safe in Java if it only access a thread safe object?

Tags: java, thread-safety

Suppose to use an object of a Java class declared to be **thread safe** (e.g. [`HttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpClient.html) from *Apache Commons*) as follows:

```
public class MyClass{
    private HttpClient myClient;

    public HttpClient getClient(){
      return myClient;
    }
}
```

Is the `getClient()` method thread safe since `myClient` is *thread safe* and I only return it or I must declare it `synchronized` or I need to use a `Lock` to declare it thread safe?

Comment: I don't think you need to declare `getClient()` synchronized.

Comment: And where are you initialising myClient?

Comment: @Jai in the constructor...

Comment: You may want to declare it `final` if you don't need to reassign myClient value. 
That will save you from yourself and keep the thread-safety

Comment: @user2256686 I do not agree! Declaring the object myClient as final doesn't mean that its state cannot be modified! It must be thread safe (as all the implementations of HttpClient are) in order to avoid problem with concurrent programming.

Comment: @mat_boy You're right. But, you declared that myClient is already thread safe.

Comment: @user2256686 I replied to what you claimed, i.e. that declaring it `final` will "_keep the thread-safety_". Making an object final doesn't ensure that it will be thread safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to declare the synchronized stuff because getClient is not going to return different values for different getClient calls